# Android : How to know if an android app is running efficiently (Newbie)

Tags: android-studio

I am new to android programming and I'm currently making a Home launcher app with some tools for my thesis. Android programming is not taught in my school so I'm sorry if this seems quite a newbie/stupid question, I really need help. I have my Launcher made already but I am very anxious if it works efficient especially if a user would use it for a long time. I read up a lot on life cycle tricks and stumbled upon fragments and asyncTask which all seemed complicated and the examples I've looked up are somehow opting out some methods, there were also a lot of blogs about how messy fragments are and how it causes a lot of hard to debug errors. My app isn't implementing both fragments and asynctask but it runs fine on my phone and in other phones I've tried but I just wanna know if there is any method I can check if it is efficient or if it won't lag and waste battery and storage and I also wanna know specific cases on which it is really necessary to implement asynctask/fragments. If there is a tutorial a newbie can understand please also give a link. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: use android device monitor available with android studio. It helps you to check how much resources your app is consuming

Comment: Can it track even physical devices? How do I know if it's consuming just enough for a home launcher?

Comment: yes you can. Use the icon to to the left of attach debugger icon.It is known as profiler

Comment: Thank you so much :) I will try it now

Comment: Just one tip, If there are logs (log.d) in your code remove them. it will make your application run more smooth.

Comment: Thank you, I will absolutely try that. How do I check for drawable leaks and delay in response time?